# Form entries are not storing in Database table after clicking on Submit (PHP and MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, validation

Form URL : https://space-learning.com/#toregister

When successfully submitting the form after filling in all the fields then it showing blank page error with no response and values are not storing in the database table so I think there's some code issues don't know what also I have rechecked all the codes many times but still showing blank page when executing the file **rprocessnew.php** after clicking on **Submit** button as mentioned that file codes though.

**rprocessnew.php**

```
<?php

include 'library/function.php';'config.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

extract($_POST);
$hash = md5(rand(1000,9999));
$uniqueid = "";
     
        
$arr="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
$arr1='0123456789';
$a=str_shuffle($arr);
$b=str_shuffle($arr1);
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{
$uniqueid.=$a[rand($i, strlen($a)-1)];
$uniqueid.=$b[rand($i, strlen($b)-1)];

}
        
     if($pass!=$cnfpass){
      echo '<script>alert("Please match password and confirm password")</script>';
      echo '<script>window.location.href="https://www.space-learning.com#toregister"</script>';
      exit;
     }


if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email']) AND isset($_POST['hash']) && !empty($_POST['hash'])){
        
    // Verify data
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']); // Turn our post into a local variable 
    $hash = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['hash']); // Turn our post into a local variable 

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO user1 (userid, schoolcode, school_location, schoolname, name, class, section, email, pass, hash, mobile, uniqueid) VALUES( 
        '". mysqli_real_escape_string($student_uid) ."', 
        '". mysqli_real_escape_string($school_code) ."', 
        '". mysqli_real_escape_string($school_location) ."', 
        '". mysqli_real_escape_string($school_name) ."', 
        '". mysqli_real_escape_string($name) ."', 
        '". mysqli_real_escape_string($class) ."', 
        '". mysqli_real_escape_string($section) ."', 
        '". mysqli_real_escape_string($email) ."', 
        '". mysqli_real_escape_string($pass) ."',
        '". mysqli_real_escape_string($hash) ."', 
        '". mysqli_real_escape_string($mobile) ."',  
        '". mysqli_real_escape_string($uniqueid) ."') ") or die(mysqli_error($con));
        
}


// Email Message
    $to      = $email; 
    $subject = 'Signup | Verification'; 
    $message = '
    
    Hi '.$name.',
     
    Welcome to the World of ASTRONOMY!
    
    You have successfully registered for the SPACE Astronomy Club. Now, you are just one click away to activate your account.<br>For activation, you need to click the given link and enter the Username as well as Password provided below.
     
    ------------------------
    Username: '.$email.'
    Password: '.$pass.'
    -------------------------
    
    Please click this link to activate your account:  https://www.space-learning.com/verifynew.php?email='.$email.'&hash='.$hash.'
    
    SPACE Astronomy Club page has all the required data that you may need through the various club sessions, such as: 
    
      - Reading Material
    
      - Further Reading
    
      - Challenge Yourself and Many More
    
    We are also providing you with a Unique ID that you can use for being a lifetime beneficiary of SPACE products.
    
    Your Unique ID: '.$uniqueid.'
    
    You may get the following benefits using the Unique Id:
    
    Whenever there will be a new release of any new product then you will get the privilege to use it.
    
    You will get the life time membership for same even if you have completed the module1 and module 2.
    
    Moreover, you will be getting discounts on a number of space products like, Astroport Visits, Astronomers Tool, etc.
    Any offer can be taken only once per Unique id.
    
    ';
    // Our message above including the link
                         
    $headers = 'From:Space Technology and Education Pvt. Ltd.<getintouch@space-india.com>' . "\r\n"; // Set from headers
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send our email

?>
```

So kindly suggest me the main cause for this error and Thanks in Advance :)

I have rechecked all the file codes for searching the main cause for this no response error but nothing found and also I don't have much knowledge in advance for Mysql terminologies.

Comment: No really sure what output you expect - your code does not produce any.

Comment: Yes it's showing blank page even after I have already enabled the error displaying header  tags so why though?

Comment: Then you have to print out the values of input parameters and results of various calculations made in your code to debug your code. Probably your code does not even go into the if that has the database operation.

Comment: Have you checked that all the variables in your query are actually coming through from the form when you debugged the code? What does mysqli return when you execute the query? You should also read up on Prepared Statements rather than concatenating all those variables directly into the query string.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but if you have a `school_code`, why do you also need to store the school name and school location in this table? Surely only the code is needed, and you can retrieve the remainder from the school table?

Comment: It also looks as if you are storing the password in plain text, which is really not a very good idea. Read up on `password_hash()` to store it, and `password_verify()` to verify it when the user tries to log in, or whatever they do with the password. It's also not a good idea to send it in plain text in an email - if your user forgets it, send them a link to reset it, don't send them a note of what it is.

Comment: `it's showing blank page even after I have already enabled the error displaying header tags so why though?`...well, simply look at your code. Which part of the code do you _expect_ is responsible for outputting anything? The only `echo` statements are given in the case where two passwords don't match. Every other scenario doesn't have any `echo` or similar statement. So...the answer is easy: your code doesn't output anything because you didn't tell it to.

Comment: P.S. If you're asking why it doesn't output anything when you think there's been a database error, then that'll be because you haven't enabled PHP error reporting, and/or haven't enabled mysqli error reporting. But it's unclear whether there's been a database error, or whether the code never even reached the `mysqli_query` command - perhaps it didn't enter the `if` block at all? Do some basic [debugging](https://www.atatus.com/blog/debugging-in-php/) and then you'll be able to see what your code is really doing, and what data it's processing.